# Bend a plane in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created this curved plane using geometry nodes:
[image: Curved plane]

[image: Node SETUP]

Now I want to curve the whole plane around the y-axis. Imagine it's a plate that I want to wrap around a cylinder. Is there a way to do it in GN?

Comment: Not really. I don't really like the fact that you have to create an array of objects to form the shape of bent objects. It could suffice as a workaround but I think in this case it's very tedious for a very simple operation.

Comment: you didn't understand or download the example file. the node "deform" Robin made deforms without array...this was just added additionally because of the question.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I don't understand how it works. I have very little experience. I'll need to study the node setup in the file to see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: no problem. just open up a question here what you don't understand. I am pretty sure someone can and will help.